# Submit form using VueJs and AJAX in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5.1, vue.js, vue-resource

I am trying to submit a form using AJAX and VueJs. But somehow I am failing to achieve that. I always end up getting an empty `Illuminate\Http\Request` object.

The blade file:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <generate-admin></generate-admin>
    </div>

    <script src="https:http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ url('/js/main.js') }}"></script>
</body>
```

The component:

```
<template>
    <form id="createAdministrator" @submit.prevent="createAdministrator">

        <div class="form-group">

           <input type="text"
                  name="username"
                  id="txtUserName"
                  placeholder="Username"
                  autocomplete="off"
                  v-model="username"
           />

        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit">

    </form>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data: function() {
            return {
                username: ''
            }
        },

        methods: {
            createAdministrator: function() {
                formContents = jQuery("#createAdministrator").serialize();

                this.$http.post('/admin', formContents).then(function(response, status, request) {
                    console.log(response);
                }, function() {
                    console.log('failed');
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**`main.js`**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import GenerateAdmin from './components/GenerateAdmin.vue';

var VueResource = require('vue-resource')
Vue.use(VueResource);

Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = document.querySelector('#token').getAttribute('content');
Vue.http.options.emulateJSON = true;

new Vue({
    el: 'body',

    components: { GenerateAdmin }
});
```

**`gulpfile.js`**

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

require('laravel-elixir-vueify');

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.browserify('main.js');
});
```

**`routes.php`**

```
Route::get('/admin/create', function () {
    return view('admin.create');
});

Route::post('/admin', function(Request $request) {
    // returns an empty object.
    return response(['results' => $request]);
});

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

What I get in return is:

```
"{"results":{"attributes":{},"request":{},"query":{},"server":{},"files":{},"cookies":{},"headers":{}}}"
```

When I check the Request Payload section of Network Tab in Chrome. I do see that the form is getting submitted successfully with whatever data I write in the text box above.

Why is this happening ? Kindly guide me where I have made the mistake ?

---

**UPDATE 1:**

I was playing trial and error with the code above. And I removed the namespace `Illuminate\Http\Request` and also removed the argument `Request $request` from the `post` Route. And changed the passing parameter to object from string.

Doing so, did the job for me that I was looking for. Why I don't know. I am still looking for someone who can explain this to me.

Why adding the namespace `Iluminate\Http\Request` in `routes.php` file didn't work as I was expecting and removing it did the task ?

Can anybody tell me why it didn't worked out earlier ? Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

---

**P.S.:** I have started learning VueJs Components recently.

Comment: I have never tried jQuery().serialize(), instead I prefer to set a json data object in Vue component and then send that data object with the post request. In your `createAdministrator()` try sending `this.username` as the request data and see what you get. for ex: `createAdministrator(){this.$http.post('/admin', this.username).then(response => {console.log(response);})`

Comment: @Donkarnash Nope.. That also didn't worked.. Same thing happened.. Returned an empty object..

Comment: Just a hunch, haven't tried it. But doesn't .serialize() return a string like: "username=WhateverTheInputIs"? I think what you want is to post an object like: { 'username': WhateverTheInputIs }.

Answer (score 2):

As a general practice I follow, any form data which needs to be passed to the laravel controller is passed as json object from vue frontend. Then in laravel controller (route with a closure function in your case) the values from the received json object are retrieved by using `$request->get('key')`.
So in your case the component code could be

```js
    <template>
    <form id="createAdministrator" @submit.prevent="createAdministrator">

        <div class="form-group">

           <input type="text"
                  name="username"
                  id="txtUserName"
                  placeholder="Username"
                  autocomplete="off"
                  v-model="username"
           />

        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit">

    </form>
</template>

<script>
    export default{
      template:require('./generate-admin-template.html'),
      data() {
          return {
              username: ''
          }
      },
      computed:{
        formData(){
          return {
            username:this.username
          }
        }
      },
      methods: {
          createAdministrator: function() {
              this.$http.post('/admin', this.formData).then(function(response) {
                  console.log(response);
              }, function() {
                  console.log('failed');
              });
          }
      }
    }
</script>
```

Then in your `routes.php` file

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/admin/create', function () {
    return view('admin.create');
});

Route::post('/admin', function (Request $request) {
    return response(['results' => $request->get('username')]);
});
```

I guess the `Illuminate\Http\Request` instance returns a `$request - Collection` so we need to access the values using `Methods available on Collections`.
I have tested the above code along with your code for `main.js` and `'/admin/create'`.
One more thing - I think if you send serialized form data to the controller, then within the controller it needs to be de-serialized in order to get object or array containing `$key=>$value` pairs to facilitate fetching required data.

Comment: Seems you master vue.js. I need your help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41843823/how-to-display-button-link-with-vue-js

Answer (score 0):

All variables ($attributes, $request, $query, etc) on Request and SymfonyRequest classes are protected, since neither class implements __toString, php does its best to give you what it can.

If you need to see each value, you need to call correct getter. Something like:

```
Route::post('/admin', function(Request $request) {    
    return response(['server' => $request->server(), 'form'=>$request->all()]);
});
```

Comment: Inspect your JS code, review requests in browser and check Laravel's site here https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests#retrieving-input